# The very basics of WPF Databinding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I've just started working with WPF, and to start with, I'd like to know how to programatically add instances of my own custom class with the one property of 'Name' to a listbox, and the listbox will show each element as its name in the UI, rather than as "MyNamespace.CustomClass".

I've read vague things about DataContexts and DataBinding and DataTemplates, but I want to know the absolute minimum I can do, preferably with as little XAML as possible - I find it fairly bewildering.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no real workaround from XAML. You'll need to deal with it. And it makes some things really easy, too! There are enough tutorials at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx).

Comment: DataContexts and DataBinding is the absolute minimum of WPF

Comment: It seems like every tutorial uses huge amounts of XAML and the relevant sections to the topic are never clear. I know I'll need to be able to deal with some, however.

Comment: If you don't want to use xaml, databinding and so, why do you want to program in wpf? You could use winforms instead.

Comment: For the same of learning WPF. I need to start somewhere.

Comment: it seems you managed to get your listbox to display list of your custom class, is thatcorrect

Comment: Yes, I manually added instances of this class to the ListBox.Items property, but I suspect that isn't the correct way to do it.

Comment: could just override .ToString() and it'll appear in the list box instead of the class name.

Comment: then add "DisplayMemberPath="Name" to the listbox in XAML, or as @Andy said just override ToString() in your class

Comment: I think that's the answer I'm looking for. And it didn't involve (formal) databinding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you want to avoid binding but I'll throw this out there anyway. try not to be too scared of XAML, it's a bit crazy to start with but once you get used to all of the {binding}s it's actually pretty obvious, a simple example of binding a listbox to a collection in code behind would go something like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

The DataContext property in Window tells it where bindings will look by default (which in this case is the window) and the data template tells the list box how to display each item found in the collection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<MyClass>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<MyClass>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
            Items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item1" });
            Items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item2" });
            Items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item3" });
            Items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item4" });
            Items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item5" });
        }
    }
}
```

When pasted in to Visual Studio as is the above code should show this.
[image]

Comment: Okay you've convinced me to try. I basically copied your code, changing the datatypes and property names wherever relevant. However the list view shows nothing - no items, even though the debugger says the 'Items' collection is filled. Are you sure your code works? It could well be my mistake though.

Comment: I just tried copying in the code to a new project, pasted the results as an image, seems to work fine.

Comment: Ah yes it was my fault - I didn't understand the syntax so I somehow defined a second listbox inside the first one... But thank you for this simple explanation, it's just what I needed!